# dhtmlxGrid How to select the value for sorting?

Tags: javascript, sorting, grid, dhtmlx, gridview-sorting

I've been playing with the filtering and sorting in dhtmlxGrid (https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/08_filtering/01_pro_filter.html) and I have a question: Can we sort the column with the employees' names by the last names without the changing the way they are written?

E.g.:

We have:

1. Alex Calson
2. David Edmond
3. James Brightwood

And after sorting we want to have the names in this order:

1. James Brightwood
2. Alex Calson
3. David Edmond

Is it possible?

Comment: You should add some code to your question so people know you've at least made an attempt and give people a better understanding of how you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for you to reach the required functionality is to create a custom sorting function that will sort the column only by the second part of the value.
Here you can find a tutorial:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__sorting.html#customsortingfunction

and a simple working example:

http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/146a327f0